# How to implement an integration filter on arrays?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, syntax, filtering

I have the discrete integration filters:

$$y(n) = Ax(n) + By(n−p) , \text{$A$, $B$ real constants, $p$ positive integer}$$

EDIT: in the initial version of this question I focussed only on the case $A=B=p=1$

I want to apply it on an array representing an impulse signal `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (assuming $x(n) = y(n) = 0$ for every $n < 0$)

In the imperative style, using Python, I would write:

```
>>> x = [0]*5
>>> y = [0]*5
>>> impulse = [1]+[0]*5

>>> for i in impulse:
...   x += [i]
...   y += [i+y[-1]]
... 

>>> x
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> y
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

How can I obtain the same result with Mathematica? I saw the [FoldList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) and [MovingMap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html) functions that had some potential to solve similar problems. But they seem to work only on *one* list, and I wasn't able to make them use both the $x$ and $y$ lists at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pardon me if this is wildly off base, but is this useful?

```
RecurrenceFilter[{{1, 0, -B}, {A}}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A, 0, A B, 0, A B^2, 0}
> ```

From [the Wolfram Language documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceFilter.html):

> `RecurrenceFilter[{α,β},x]` gives the response $y$ to the causal input $x$ by solving the recurrence equation:
>
> $$\alpha_1 y_n + ... \alpha_i y_{n-i} = \beta_1 x_n + ... + \beta_j x_{n-j}$$
>
> for $n$ from $1$ to $Length[x]$, where $i$ is $Length[α]$ and $j$ is
>   $Length[β]$.

```
rf[n_, p_] :=
 RecurrenceFilter[{Append[UnitVector[p, 1], -B], {A}}, UnitVector[n + 6, 6]]

rf[5, 2]

rf[8, 3]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A, 0, A B, 0, A B^2, 0}
>
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A, 0, 0, A B, 0, 0, A B^2, 0, 0}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Mr. Wizard. Could you elaborate a little on how [RecurrenceFilter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceFilter.html) works? In particular, I don't how you plug the $p$ delay?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question to add a link and quote the relevant part of the doc. Feel free to revert that edit if you disagree.

Comment: @Sylvain I am glad this helped.  Sorry that I wasn't around to answer the follow-up question, but I guess you figured that out yourself.  The edit is fine.  Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = ConstantArray[0, 5];
y = ConstantArray[0, 5];
impulse = Join[{1}, ConstantArray[0, 5]];
IntegrationFilter[A_, B_, p_, impulse_, xsart_, ystart_] := 
   RecurrenceFilter[
     {Join[{1}, Table[0, p - 1], {-B}], {A}}, 
      Join[xsart, impulse], 
      ystart
   ];
```

`RecurrenceFilter` ref : http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceFilter.html

```
IntegrationFilter[1, 0, 1, impulse, x, y]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

```
IntegrationFilter[1, 1, 1, impulse, x, y]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use the recursive definition directly along with the initial condition(s):

```
Clear[y, x]
y[n_] := y[n] = a x[[n]] + b y[n - 1];
y[0] = 0;
```

To use this, you would need to define x:

```
x = ConstantArray[0, 20]; x[[3]] = x[[4]] = 1;
```

To "run" the recursion for the first few entries:

```
y /@ Range[7]

{0, 0, a, a + a b, b (a + a b), b^2 (a + a b), b^3 (a + a b)}
```

You can increase the delay (your p parameter) straightforwardly by changing y[n-1] to y[n-2] (for example), but then you also need to add another initial condition (in this case, a value for y[1]). Thanks to @OkkesDulgerci for the simplification.

Comment: `y /@ Range@7` is sufficient.